# Capture stdout and write to stdin of an existing process with Python

Tags: python-3.x, stdout, stdin

I have a Python script which needs to capture stdout and write to stdin of an *already running* process, meaning that when the script is started, the target process has been started long before it.

The process runs as a daemon, so it makes no sense to start it again.

How do I do that?

Comment: You would need to modify whatever is currently receiving its stdout and get it to redirect it to you.  Similarly, you would need to modify whatever is currently providing its stdin to accept what you want to give it.